# R - Aggregate Dates

Tags: r, date, aggregate

When aggregating an R dataframe, the dates are converted in integer :

For instance, if I want to take the maximum dates for every Id in the following dataframe :

```
> df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2), 2), b = as.Date(paste("01/01/", 2000:2003, sep=''), format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
> df1
  id          b
1  1 2000-01-01
2  2 2001-01-01
3  1 2002-01-01
4  2 2003-01-01
> aggregate(x = list(b = df1$b), by = list(id = df1$id), FUN = "max")
  id     b
1  1 11688
2  2 12053
```

Why does R behave this way ? (and what's the best way to keep a date class column in the returned dataframe?)

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Works for me... R 3.0.1.

Comment: you get a Date vector ? My R version 2.11 ; is there an environment variable that changes R behaviour on this ?

Answer (score 1):

That works for me R version 3, perhaps there were some changes in updates, so I recommend you to update R :)
As for  this version of R, have you tried as.Date() function after aggregating?
In your example, should be like:

```
    dtf2<-aggregate(x = list(b = df1$b), by = list(id = df1$id), FUN = "max")
    dtf2$b<-as.Date(dtf$b)
```

You can also add 'origin' option to as.Date, like

```
    as.Date(dtf$b, origin='1970-01-01')
```

UPD: When R looks at dates as integers, its origin is January 1, 1970.

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I confirm the results are different under R 2.11 and 3...). What guarantees that the origin date stays at 1/1/1970 ? I can't find this point in the documentation (and as the documented functions seem to be modified randomly in this language, i'm not very confident...)

Comment: Well, I don't know how to guarantee you that if you didn't find that in the documentation.
Like http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html also states about origin date, and if you search for date origin in r further you'll surely have more links stating that :)
After all it works, right? So what else you need for the guarantee? :)

Comment: Explanation in the documentation: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Dates.html
"Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates. "